# My First Kaa Application. Not able to Application CTL. Not getting any error but not able to add Schema

Tags: kaa

I am learning Kaa and trying to run  my first application following
http://kaaproject.github.io/kaa/docs/v0.10.0/Programming-guide/Your-first-Kaa-application/

Completed all the steps. Under the section, Create Schema, I created two schemas as required.

1. Data-schema.json

   ```
   {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "DataCollection",
        "namespace": "org.kaaproject.kaa.schema.MyTestApp",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "temperature",
                "type": "int"
            }
        ]
    }
   ```
2. Configuration-schema.json

   ```
   {
        "type": "record",
        "name": "Configuration",
        "namespace": "org.kaaproject.kaa.schema.MyTestApp",
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "samplePeriod",
                "type": "int",
                "by_default": 1
            }
        ]
    }
   ```

I created and tried to upload them as mentioned in step 3 under section "Create schema". Then, I tried to follow step 4, 5 and 6 under same section. Step 4, 5 and 6 are for "Adding Log Schema".

In step 6, I should get the below FQN as Existing Type
org.kaaproject.kaa.schema.MyTestApp.DataCollection

This is missing. It should be added as existing type when I performed step 1, 2 and 3 under "Create Schema" section. I am not getting any error and it's not adding.

I read that it could be because of similar FQN already present. I tried various combination but it's not working.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, I was able to find the root cause of the issue. The problem has been resolved.

Comment: Hi, I was able to find the root cause of the issue. The problem has been resolved. To add new Schema, there are 4 mandatory fields: i. Name ii. Namespace iii. Version iv. Display Name. When we upload schema.json file, the first 2 fields, "Name" and "NameSpace" are populated automatically from uploaded json file. But, last 2 fields, "Version" and "Display Name" need to be typed on UI by developer. If we do not type them, then the "Add" is not enabled. I was missing this part. Its a very silly oversight on my part. But I was stuck at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

When I meet the same problem with you, all I do is change the name of the Log Appender I will create. So it does not happen "FQN already present"